# Set the width and height of a pygame surface

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating my own GUI library with `pygame`.  I have a `UIComponent` class that creates the UI elements.  The UI element itself is created through `self.image` with `width` and `height`.  The problem with this is that changing the width and height doesn't seem to work.  I'm using `self.rect.x` to modify its coordinates but when I tried using `self.rect.width` it didn't have an effect.

```py
ui_elements = pg.sprite.Group()


class UIComponent(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width_percent, height_percent = 0, 0
        self.alignments = []
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        ui_elements.add(self)

    def set_colour(self, colour_value):
        self.image.fill(colour_value)

    def update(self, win):
        for i in self.alignments:
            i(win)

    def center_x(self, win):
        self.rect.x = (win.s_width/2)-self.image.get_width()/2

    def center_y(self, win):
        self.rect.y = (win.s_height/2)-self.image.get_height()/2

    def relative_width(self, win):
        self.rect.width = 25

    def relative_height(self, win):
        self.rect.height = 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the width and height of the `self.rect` attribute does effect the size of the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). Even if a rectangle is passed to the *dest* argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit), only the position of the rectangle is considered when the surface is _blit__ onto the target surface.
You have to scale the original image to the desired size by either [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) or [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale).
Keep the original image (`self.original_image`) and create a scaled image when the size the width or height is changed:

```py
self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original_image, self.rect.size)
```

Class `UIComponent`:

```py
class UIComponent(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.width_percent, height_percent = 0, 0
        self.alignments = []
        self.original_image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        ui_elements.add(self)

    def set_colour(self, colour_value):
        self.image.fill(colour_value)

    def update(self, win):
        for i in self.alignments:
            i(win)

    def center_x(self, win):
        self.rect.x = (win.s_width/2)-self.image.get_width()/2

    def center_y(self, win):
        self.rect.y = (win.s_height/2)-self.image.get_height()/2

    def relative_width(self, win):
        self.rect.width = 25
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original_image, self.rect.size)

    def relative_height(self, win):
        self.rect.height = 25
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original_image, self.rect.size)
```